# How to combine form elements as string and restore in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

The website have a function to let member customized the form content, therefore I can't control a number of form fields, maybe they will submit over 1000 form fields to server, over the `max_input_vars` limits, but the form fields should be unlimited, and I don't want to enlarge the number of `max_input_vars` aimlessly, so I am trying to combine all fields and value into JSON string and decode it in PHP

**FORM**

```
<form id="frm" action="get.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="chan">
   <input type="text" name="age" value="37">
   <input type="text" name="hobby" value="basketball">
   <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```

#### First try

**js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#frm').on('submit', function() {
        var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());

        $.post('get.php', {data: data}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

var_dump($data);
```

I got `"name=chan&age=37&hobby=basketball"`, I was thought I can use `parse_str` to restore it, but `parse_str` also effected by `max_input_vars`, thefore I cange `serialize()` to `serializeArray()`, and I got

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "chan"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "age"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "37"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "hobby"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "basketball"
  }
}
```

I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: why don't you use POST?

Comment: it's just an example, I used post in real function, let me change the code to avoid confused

Comment: you don't need to serialize, just use post so that params are not limited by web url link and access the data on action page

Answer (score 0):

Use array (collection) of form fields! And of course, use POST method instead of GET because GET is more limited.

```
<form id="frm" action="action.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="myfields[name]" value="chan">
  <input type="text" name="myfields[age]" value="37">
  <input type="text" name="myfields[hobby]" value="basketball">
  <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```

and then in your PHP code (action.php) fetch this array from $_POST and treat it as an array.

```
$myfields=$_POST['myfields']
foreach($myfields as $key=>$val)
{
  echo $key.':'.$val.'<br>';
}
```

you'll get:

```
name:chan
age:37
hobby:basketball
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I let member customized the form, which means they might have array elements themselves like fields[content[team_information][]]], and it will get cut in PHP, let along if I want to do in this way I have to change too much code in either JS and PHP

Comment: You can have multidimensional form fields as well likw myfields[member][customerfields]. Why not?